# Is “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet” a common or respectable English expression?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, contemporary-english

Today’s edition of the *New York Times* (December 16, 2014) carries an [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/17/opinion/you-aint-seen-nothin-yet.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=c-column-top-span-region&region=c-column-top-span-region&WT.nav=c-column-top-span-region&_r=0) written by Mark Bittman under the headline “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet.” It begins with the following passage:

> “What’s more depressing, gutting progressive moves in school nutrition
>   or gutting progressive moves in restaurant meal labeling? Neither.
>   What’s truly depressing is the “cromnibus,” the continuing resolution
>   just passed to fund the government — which contains a wide variety of
>   sometimes obscure and often corrupt riders, and signals the start of
>   plundering just about every good piece of legislation you can think
>   of, including school nutrition.”

I was a bit puzzled by the expression, “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet.” Isn’t this a double negative, which almost 65 years ago in high school I learned was an affirmative statement?

Is “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet” a common English expression to feature as the headline of one of the U.S.'s leading newspapers? What’s wrong with saying “You’ve seen nothing yet” or “You haven’t seen anything yet”? Can I say to my friend who's never traveled abroad, "You ain't seen nothin' yet"?

Comment: Try googling "double negative as an intensifier". Despite what your English teachers wanted you to believe its use is very common colloquially.

Comment: Related: [Meaning of “Ain't Seen Nothing Yet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46914/meaning-of-aint-seen-nothing-yet)

Comment: In addition to the valuable answers I received from our colleagues, I found the definition and examples of "double negative" including "You ain't nothin yet" provided in the Free Dictionary comprehensible through the search I made after posting this question.

Comment: I ain't never gonna be able to hear this phrase again without having to [sing this song.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XZWgHNcUeA)

Comment: "You ain't seen nothin' yet" is fine, but "wide variety" makes me wince.

Comment: In most cases, you should give up trying to understand repeated negatives literally in English (unlike in Japanese). You'll only injure yourself trying to keep track of them anyway. If I suddenly had a serious change of lect and said, “Ain't nobody never had no time for no none of that, yaw!” and you tried working out logically whether someone actually does or doesn't have time, you'd miss dinner before you'd figured it out. I wouldn't even have a clue myself. It's just _all_ negative.

Comment: The term 'double negative' is usually used to refer to the kind of phrase you ask about, where 'nothing' is used instead of the more formal 'anything'. That's about it. If, however, you hear two negative words together "I will never not eat breakfast", it is truly meant literally and logically (that I will always eat breakfast). This latter kind of phrase might literally have two negatives, but it would be misleading to call it a 'double negative' since that term describes the informal usage of 'nothing' instead of 'anything' (or 'no' instead of 'any' or 'a'). 'double negative' is a set phrase

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's a common, longstanding American slang idiom intended to convey that no matter what you've seen, what you are about to see will far top it (whether for good or for bad!). It has associations with pop-music and black American culture and expression, but it's a little dated --it has a retro feel to it these days.

Deliberately ungrammatical constructions are often used in pop music and advertising slogans because they are more memorable, convey a sense of "flavor" and seem more fresh and immediate.  In particular, ain't is often used as an intensifier of the negative rather than a reversal of it (the use of double negatives to intensify rather than neutralize negativity is incorrect in "standard" English, but common in black American dialect and many other non-standard English dialects).

"You haven't seen anything yet" does have the same superficial meaning, but utterly lacks the attitude of bravado and over-the-top exaggeration. If you tell your friend who hasn't traveled "you ain't seen nothing yet," you are boasting to him about the wonders that await him.  On the other hand, if you tell him "you haven't seen anything yet," you're just belittling his past experiences.  The latter expression is literal, whereas the slang expression is promotional.

Comment: +1 but I think that double negatives are not incorrect in Standard English.  They can be used to good effect to emphasize a contradictory statement in a way that a simple affirmative statement can't.

Comment: @Jim Good point, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Standard English? Is that a universally accepted term, and if so, how is it defined? Otherwise, talking about whether an expression is acceptable or not in Standard English is in many cases nonsensical, and saying an expression is or isn't acceptable in Standard English is often just trying to foist a personal point of view on others. I'd say that the quirky/punchy “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet” is perfectly acceptable in many registers, but needs scare quotes or other careful handling in the most formal registers. It would appear outlandish in a paper on organometallic chemistry, for instance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Have a read through this for the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_English

Comment: @NewWorld I already have. Have you? To quote the second section, '_Multiple definitions_:
Although Standard English is generally the most formal version of the language, a range of registers exists within Standard English, as is often seen when comparing a newspaper article with an academic paper, for example. A distinction also should be drawn between spoken and written standards. Spoken standards are traditionally looser than their written counterparts, and quicker to accept new grammatical forms and vocabulary....'

Comment: So according to this, there are multiple different standards (some for spoken English, some for written) within 'Standard English'? How is this a workable definition? An expression may be 'Standard English' and yet not 'Standard English' at the same time. 'Standard'? 'Misnomer' is the word that springs to mind.

Comment: I completely agree Edwin.  I don't want to start the next Anglo-American war, but's really annoying that 'UK English' is pushed down in favour of 'US English' by Americans referring to US English as 'Standard English'.  English is spoken in England.  The clue is in the name.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you've read the article then why did you say you didn't know how "Standard English" was defined? Clearly the term was used with reference to a particular "definition".

Comment: @Grim: It's entirely possible that "Standard English" most commonly is used to mean "the formal register of my personal idiolect", albeit it might have other more technical definitions useful for specific purposes. I think Brits are just as guilty as Americans of abusing the notion, but we're more likely to use a term like "the Queen's English" or "correct English" than "Standard English" :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added scare quotes around "standard," and uncapitalized.

Comment: @Grim I'm also against broad-brush terms like 'US English' and 'BrE'; it's not as if there's not a lot of variation nationwide, and quite a few people in the UK say choosing to use what others would label 'AmE'. The terms are misleading, giving the impression that 'AmE is what everyone in the US speaks and writes' (though one of course realises there are national _trends_).

Comment: @NewWorld The 'spoken standards' and 'written standards' decided upon aren't specified in the article.  Are we supposed to guess _which_ particular standards are meant to be included in a given person's particular definition of 'Standard English'? (See Steve Jessop's comment.) Or might we agree that the term 'definition' here isn't really fitting? It's certainly worse than useless(being open to wide misinterpretation) as it stands: person A might say 'That expression is OK in Standard English' and person B 'That expression isn't OK in Standard English' – and they might both be correct.

Comment: *Ain't is often used as an intensifier of the negative*? I find that unclear, meaningless.

Comment: @JimReynolds "You have seen nothing" is negative.  "You *ain't* seen nothing" is more intensely negative.

Comment: A more intense nothing. I can kinda see that. By *often,* do you mean a multitude of negatives, or a high frequency of nothings? Well, *I ain't got nobody to love* just came to mind. I just wonder if that's the best way to characterize the function of ain't. But I'm dropping my complaint at The Haugue.

Comment: *Intensifier* has a special meaning as a grammar term, like: *Grammar. a word, especially an adverb, or other linguistic element that indicates, and usually increases, the degree of emphasis or force to be given to the element it modifies, as very or somewhat; intensive adverb.* http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intensifier Ain't ain't one, and so the language you use is confusing to me in the context of this site. *The negative* is a vague term. The meaning of the phrase is not clear to me.

Answer (score 13):

> I was a bit puzzled with the expression, “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet.” Isn’t this a double negative, which I learnt to be an affirmative statement in high school almost 70 years ago?.

The meaning is akin to "you haven't yet seen the best, most interesting, or most exciting part".

"You ain't seen nothing yet" is a common expression -- it shows up a lot of different places. For example, James Brown's 1967 hit  ["Soul Man"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sn4EMQtbcq0#t=50s):

> Got what I got, the hard way
>
> And I'll make it better each and every day
>
> So honey don't you fret
>
> 'Cause **you ain't seen nothin' yet**

Here the singer is telling his "honey" not to worry about their present condition (presumably not very good) -- because the best is yet to come.

This usage, as a reassuring or motivational statement, is very common. Here's the CEO of telecommunications company telling investors that despite poor performance, they should be patient, because [exciting changes are ahead](http://www.cnet.com/news/sprint-ceo-teases-big-promotional-push-you-aint-seen-nothing-yet/):

> Sprint looks poised to continue upping the ante, with [Sprint CEO Marcelo] Claure teasing more promotions and discounts to come. "You ain't seen nothing yet," Claure said, adding that the next two to three weeks has him "extremely excited."

As for the other part of your question,

> What’s wrong with saying “You’ve seen nothing yet” or “You haven’t seen anything yet”?

Grammatically speaking, "you haven't seen anything yet" is a better choice (the other alternative you suggested, "you've seen nothing yet", seems a bit condescending).

But that's a very dry, robotic way of saying it. Such is the nature of English idioms (or idioms in any language, really): they add color and connotation beyond their literal meanings and constructions.

Comment: Also B.T.O. had a hit in the 70's with that exact title.

Comment: @Octopus: Yep! James Brown's usage predates BTO's by quite a bit, though.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are attributing this to James Brown or BTO - the phrase is famously associated with Jimmy Durante. However, I think something close to the expression possibly dates back much further. (Still trying to confirm an attribution to Cervantes). Edit: [it's here](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Cervantes) as "Thou hast seen nothing yet."

Comment: @Glen_b: I wasn't saying that was the original usage -- but both James Brown and BTO _did_ say it in different contexts.

Comment: @Glen_b That's not a double neg though? Just the same as "You have seen nothing yet", isn't it?

Comment: @Ollie Correct, it's not a double negative, but given the earlier expression clearly existed, the change from "hast" to "ain't" (going from written word to spoken phrase across centuries and countries) is relatively minor and hardly surprising; certainly the "ain't" was in use by Durante.

Comment: @Glen_b But the Cervantes attribution isn't a double negative (or should that be _ain't not_ a double negative:-)).  The most famous variant I know would be Al Jolson's "_You ain't **heard** nothin' yet_" in the "The Jazz Singer" -- the first "talkie".  This was in 1927, although he'd been using the phrase (on stage) since 1918 (see [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jazz_Singer#Introducing_sound))

Answer (score 2):

Although grammatically incorrect, the phrase has gained a sort of acceptability through being repeated over the years. I seem to remember something along those lines from an old film ('The Jazz Singer'?) about Al Jolson.

Answer (score 1):

In this context *ain’t* is used as part of a figure of speech and is acceptable.  *Ain’t* is the vernacular form of *am not* and is considered poor grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of [document from the US Congress](https://books.google.com/books?id=KVBHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22ain%27t+seen+nothing+yet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuvMzT85vPAhWBMyYKHeU-DsI4ChDoAQhGMAk#v=onepage&q=%22ain%27t%20seen%20nothing%20yet%22&f=false), dated 1877:

> Well, you see how we have commenced it, but *you ain't seen nothing yet* to what you will see before this is over.

A few others around that date, and then the references come hot and heavy beginning in the mid-1920s.  Apparently [some popular songs](https://books.google.com/books?id=gNYiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1798&dq=%22ain%E2%80%99t+heard+nothing+yet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuuNTZ9pvPAhWBVSYKHaKxBoI4ChDoAQg1MAU#v=onepage&q=%22ain%E2%80%99t%20heard%20nothing%20yet%22&f=false) in the late 1910s employed the phrase "You ain't heard nothin' yet", and the singer Al Jolson picked it up as a catch phrase (and famous line in the 1927 movie *The Jazz Singer*).  It was an obvious swap from "heard" to "seen" and back, once the phrase became idiomatic.

You can argue that it's wrong, but it's been part of the American idiom for over 100 years.